# In Paramiko, how can I determine if a successful connection was via the SSH key or the password?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

This code excerpt connects properly if the private ssh key **OR** the password is correct (it tries the key first). After a successful connection, how can I tell which one was used? Is this even possible without first trying to connect with the key only (no password)? I cannot find this in the [Paramiko documention](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/client.html).

```
self.client = paramiko.SSHClient()
hostkey = self.ssh_hostkey.split(' ')
self.client.get_host_keys().add(self.ip, hostkey[0], paramiko.RSAKey(data=base64.b64decode(hostkey[1])))
privkey_file = io.StringIO()
privkey_file.write(self.ssh_privkey)
privkey_file.seek(0)
privkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(privkey_file)
try:
    self.client.connect(
        hostname=self.ip,
        username='root',
        pkey=privkey,
        password=self.router_password, # will try private key first, then password
        allow_agent=False,
        look_for_keys=False,
    )
    self.last_connect = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime())
    print_msg(1, "Connected to {}".format(self.nickname))
except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException:
    self.client = None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that `SSHClient` gives you that information (apart from you parsing a log file).

You would have to resort to low-level [`Transport` class](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/transport.html).

With it, you can do [`Transport.auth_publickey`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/transport.html#paramiko.transport.Transport.auth_publickey) and fallback to [`Transport.auth_password`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/transport.html#paramiko.transport.Transport.auth_password), without having to reopen a session.

```
transport = paramiko.Transport(host)
transport.connect(hostkey)

try:
    print("Trying key")
    transport.auth_publickey(username, key)
except:
    print("Trying password")
    transport.auth_password(username, password)

print("Authenticated")
```